# When presenting the iOS HealthKit permissions modal view, the view behind it is black

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

When calling the *HKHealthStore*'s *requestAuthorizationToShareTypes* method, a modal permissions view is presented.

In my current app, *requestAuthorizationToShareTypes* is called when the user presses a button. When the automatic modal permissions view from HealthKit is presented (and dismissed), there is a visible black background behind it instead of the view controller from which it is displayed.

When presenting any other view modally in my application, this does not occur. Has anybody else had this experience or have any ideas of what I could try? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing this same behavior. Are you already presenting a modal when you call requestAuthorizationToShareTypes?

Comment: I've also only seen this on iOS 9 and I'm curious whether you're seeing it on earlier iOS versions

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in iOS 9.  You should file a bug with Apple.

Comment: been banging my head for half a day on this..just saw this and tested on ios 8. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: It believe it should be fixed in iOS 9.x, not sure which release though.